# Python - How to look up multiple characters in a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to make a piece of code that converts an 8 digit binary string to hexadecimal however it does not seem to output anything, I think that the problem is in looking up the characters in the binary but I am not sure. The code is as follows:

```
number = input("Enter your binary number: ")
    if len(number) < 8:
        for i in range(0,8-len(number)):
            newnumber = "0"+number
            number = newnumber
    endnumber = ["",""]
    result = ""
    for i in range(2):
        if i == 1:
            startnumber = number[0:3]
        else:
            startnumber = number[4:7]
        if startnumber == "0000":
            result = result + "0"
        elif startnumber == "0001":
            result = result + "1"
        elif startnumber == "0010":
            result = result + "2"
        elif startnumber == "0011":
            result = result + "3"
        elif startnumber == "0100":
            result = result + "4"
        elif startnumber == "0101":
            result = result + "5"
        elif startnumber == "0110":
            result = result + "6"
        elif startnumber == "0111":
            result = result + "7"
        elif startnumber == "1000":
            result = result + "8"
        elif startnumber == "1001":
            result = result + "9"
        elif startnumber == "1010":
            result = result + "A"
        elif startnumber == "1011":
            result = result + "B"
        elif startnumber == "1100":
            result = result + "C"
        elif startnumber == "1101":
            result = result + "D"
        elif startnumber == "1110":
            result = result + "E"
        elif startnumber == "1111":
            result = result + "F"
    print(result)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: why not `hex(int('1010101', 2))`?

Comment: Note that `range(2)` counts `0, 1`, not `1, 2`, so you will do `number[4:7]` first, and then `number[0:3]`

Comment: Great, that's fixed it doing the second character first, I always assumed that it was 1 then 2 rather than 0 then 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in how you're slicing your string. Specifically with `startnumber = number[0:3]` and `startnumber = number[4:7]`.

Use `startnumber = number[0:4]` and `startnumber = number[4:8]`.

## Why?

`startnumber = number[0:3]` gives you the first 3 characters in `number` (i.e., `number[0]`, `number[1]`, and `number[2]`)

Ex:

```
> number = "00001111"
> startnumber = number[0:3]
> print(startnumber)
'000'
> startnumber = number[0:4]
> print(startnumber)
'0000'
> startnumber = number[4:8]
> print(startnumber)
'1111'
```

EDIT: As mentioned in your question's comments, there's also a problem with your assignment of `startnumber`. Take note that Python (and most programming languages) are *zero-indexed*, meaning iterations generally start at `0` and end at `n-1`. So `range(2)` actually iterates from `0` to `1`, excluding `2`.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong on so many levels.

1) It's builtin

```
int(number, 2)
```

2) If you want do it manually

```
result = 0
for index, char in enumerate(number[::-1]):
    if char == '1':
        result += 2^index
```